# Can't playback with videos as textures

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I am very new to texture painting.

I'm trying to paint a video on an plane, but it won't start when I press play.

I enabled auto refresh and set an end keyframe but it doesn't work.

i am trying yo achive the result in the second image with video rather then images

[image]

[image]

Comment: Texture painting allows you to paint on an image (the one called `Untitled` on the left window). Since it's just an image, it won't animate when you press play. Can you explain your problem a bit more ? What are you trying to do?

Comment: vklidu got it right thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such effect you paint black&white texture and use this mask as mix Factor in material node-tree ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Blend file can't pack movie files, so use your or [here](https://player.vimeo.com/external/559861554.sd.mp4?s=0cbd69cb389727d0ef1704e0906d5ba82bb2aef0&profile_id=165&oauth2_token_id=57447761) is source I used in the example.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to do several of those on one plane, is it possible with that technique

Comment: Several of what ...? ... Could you be a more specific or attach some mockup to understand what is your goal? Thanks

Comment: my bad...  i mean multiple videos on one plane  
i added an image to the original post @vklidu

Comment: Easy to try ... just add another Mix node to mix two videos, paint another mask and use as Factor.